# Use GCloud CLI to list secrets that have label but no value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager, gcloud-cli

We use labels in Secret Manager to label secrets corresponding to a particular service, for example, "reports" vs "rostering", and I would like to be able to list secrets with such a label, however, these labels have **no** value, so this fails to return any results:

```
gcloud secrets list --filter="labels.reports:*"
```

How can I use the gcloud CLI to list secrets matching a label with no value?

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve the desired [filtering](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) effect for valueless labels by looking for those that are less than one of the last ASCII characters:

```
gcloud secrets --project 'khan-academy' list --format json --filter 'labels.reports<}'
```

The GCP console (where regular valueless label filtering works) sends an HTTP request to https://cloudconsole-pa.clients6.google.com/v3/entityServices/SecretsEntityService/schemas/SECRETS_GRAPHQL:batchGraphql, with payload:

```
{locale: "en_US", orderBy: [{field: "name", order: "ASCENDING"}], filter: "labels:prod#*"}
```

However, `labels:prod#*` doesn't work with the gcloud CLI.